# Refresh Page Automatically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I will be creating a JQuery slide show, but need the page to refresh every 5 minutes to change the content.

I know I can do this via some Javascript, but this can be altered on the client side to avoid page refreshes. Is there a way for the server to timeout a page and force a refresh?

Comment: Both answers currently in place are right: A) You can't force this from the server, and B) You can most easily do this with a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) header.

Comment: So you worry that your customers hack into your page's javascript and change the behaviour?

Comment: Yes I am worried about that @Yogu as there needs to be sections of adverts and this could be avoided by changing the refresh time

Comment: That is the nature of html and the web. You cannot control the client side.

Comment: Ok, but then I'm sorry - it's the client's machine, so you can't force anything. The mentioned `Refresh` header can be easily avoided by pressing Esc. Probably a small fraction of your users would alter the javascript so the deficit would not be that bad, would it?

Comment: No it wouldn't be that bad. I was just wondering if there was any other option / work around

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to a javascript reload, you can send a  refresh header:

```
header("Refresh: 300;url='http://thepage.com/example'");
```

The browser will redirect after 300 seconds regardless of javascript. It can be disabled in configuration of the browser though, but it's not commonly disabled.

Answer (score 18):

Meta refresh will work very simply:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

The 300 means it will refresh every 300 seconds or 5 minutes. In this way you don't use JavaScript so there is no way the user can turn it off.

Comment: This is exactly what Esailija's answer does.

Comment: I prefer a real header, it cannot be seen in source ;P

Comment: Of course PHP would also work well and yes, you may not want to not include it in the source.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way you can **force** the page to reload from the server.

The way to do it in JavaScript is simple:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Although this could be overridden on the client side, reguler users won't be messing around with your script.

---

**As a side note:** Is there any reason you're so *adamant* on reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

**The JavaScript Method**

```
var timer = null;

function auto_reload()
{
  window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php';
}

<body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',10000);">
```

Answer (score 1):

**The META Tag Method**

```
The following refreshes the page every 30 seconds.

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using PHP

I would use a php function that can be called on any page without having to set the url

```
    // write the function
    function refresh( $time ){
        $current_url = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
        return header( "Refresh: " . $time . "; URL=$current_url" );
    }

    // call the function in the appropriate place
    refresh( 4 );   
    // this refreshes page after 4 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do that reload is using `window.location`:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "YOUR_PAGE_URL";
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for the anonymous function.